# Why is there a horse skeleton in the 2005 movie Sahara?

Tags: production-mistakes, sahara

In the 2005 film [Sahara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahara_(2005_film)) there is an odd moment where a strange skeleton appears. Here's a screen shot:

[image: Still showing skeleton in background]

It is the scene about 1 hour 40 minutes into the movie - just after Al jumps out to avoid getting burned.

Obviously, it was some sort of glitch where something changed, and the scene didn't get edited out. Wondering what the back story is - why they thought there would be some sort of large animal there.

Comment: That doesn't look like any kind of animal skeleton to me.

Comment: So yeah, not a horse skeleton... but I do see how it sort of looks like part of a large ribcage.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out but it's not a horse skeleton...

### ...it's a melted floor walkway panel.

Zahn does the "running down a tunnel away from flame blast" thing and leaps to safety...from the walkway.

In your original image you can see that the melted walkway connects to the walkway in the tunnel.

[image]

[image]

[image]